# How to get html from mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express

I have collection

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "title" : "Title",
    "description" : "<p>Text ...</p>",
}
```

I need to get the description in Angular.
But when I output this data, I get a string `<p>Text ...</p>` instead of a tag `<p>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<span [innerHtml]="yourObject.description"></span>
```